# manipulating SVGs with python

Tags: python, svg

I want to read an existing SVG file, traverse all elements and remove them if they match certain conditions (e.g. remove all objects with red border).

There is the `svgwrite` library for Python2/3 but the tutorials/documentation I found only show how to add some lines and save the file.

Can I also manipulate/remove existing elements inside an SVG document with `svgwrite`? If not - is there an alternative for Python?

Answer (score 0):

The svgwrite package only creates svg. It does not read a svg file. I have not tried any packages to read and process svg files.